# Terraform Unreadable module directory

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform configuration as:

[image: File configuration]

trying to use the service account in main.tf as

```
################# General Settings #################################
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.project_region
}

module "serivce_account" {
  source = "./service_account"
  
}
```

but im getting the following erros

```
C:\Users\\Documents\terraform\dashboards-infrastructure\test>terraform init
Initializing modules...
- serivce_account in
╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory
│
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: CreateFile service_account: The system cannot find the file specified.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to read module directory
│
│ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
╵

╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory
│
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: CreateFile service_account: The system cannot find the file specified.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to read module directory
│
│ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
```

why can't terraform see my service account module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `service_acount`, not `service_account`. You have mistake in folder name.

Comment: Also, spelled the module name `serivce_account`. :)